# Kubernetes pod export environment variables from command

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, vault

I am trying to export environment to an Openshift pod via command. Currently I am able to leverage the command argument to run shell scripts (echo hi as example):

```yaml
containers:
  command: 
    ['sh', '-c', 'echo hi && /opt/app-root/src/communities/entry.sh; node /opt/app-root/src/communities/main.js; echo $?']
```

This works well to start up my pod with the logs:

```
hi
Starting application on 0.0.0.0:8080
```

However, when I go to export environment variables they do not persist, in this example I'm trying to export MYVAR for use in the pod:

```yaml
containers:
  command: 
    ['sh', '-c', 'export MYVAR=THIS && /opt/app-root/src/communities/entry.sh; node /opt/app-root/src/communities/main.js; echo $?']
```

This starts up the pod but MYVAR is not defined!

My end goal is to be able to run a script from Vault at pod start up:

```yaml
containers:
  command: 
    ['sh', '-c', 'source /vault/secrets/EXSECRET && /opt/app-root/src/communities/entry.sh; node /opt/app-root/src/communities/main.js; echo $?']
```

Is there a way to set environment variables using a shell command after pod start up?

I've been stuck on this for quite some time and appreciate the help.

EDIT: My config

```yaml
# THIS PART MOUNTS TO /vault/secrets/test ^
annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-test: namespace-nonprod/test
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-test: |
          {{`{{- with secret "namespace-nonprod/test" -}}
          export dev_database_host="{{ .Data.data.test1 }}"
          export dev_database_name="{{ .Data.data.test2 }}"
          {{- end }}`}}

 containers:
        - resources: {}
          command:
            ['sh', '-c']
          args:
            ['source /vault/secrets/test && /opt/app-root/src/communities/entry.sh; node /opt/app-root/src/communities/main.js']  # not working ^
```

I can see the file is correctly mounted:

```
sh-4.4$ cat /vault/secrets/test
export dev_database_host="asdf1"
export dev_database_name="asdf2"
```

yet they are not available to env.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think the environment variable isn't being set?  `source` is not a POSIX standard Bourne shell command; do you need `.` instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't think the env var is being set as it isn't defined when I list env. Interestingly, once the pod has spun up I am able to manually run source /vault/secrets/test and then they are defined when listing env :)

Comment: Can you show the code in your application that accesses the environment?  What exactly are you doing when you "list env"?  (If it's a `kubectl exec` debugging shell, that's in a secondary process that sees the Kubernetes `env:` variables, but it won't see environment variables only set within the main process.)

Comment: Interesting. I'm navigating to the pod terminal and just executing the command: 
```
env
```
Do you have any suggestions for how to test if they are indeed defined? Note it's not kubectl and from the Openshift UI thanks

Comment: I'd add a log message to your application code.  "Pod terminal" is not that useful, especially in Kubernetes where you will typically have multiple replicas of a Pod and where the cluster can destroy them without your involvement in a couple of cases.

Answer (score 0):

When you set an environment variable, you set a `local` env, `NOT GLOBAL`. When you log out, your `env` is gone.

The best way to set a global env in Kubernetes is to set the env in a `configMap`(`secret`) and mount the `configMap`(`secret`) into the `deployment`(or `statefulset`).

Another approach is to set the `Env` directly in your `deployment` definition. More in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately for my use case I don't believe setting the config map / directly in ENV will work as these secrets are sourced from [vault](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/injector/examples#vault-agent-injector-examples). Where the guide mentions ' A template should be created that exports a Vault secret as an environment variable and the application container should source those files during startup'

Comment: I could not understand the difficulty with the `configmap`(in this case `secret` is better). You get the secrets from the vault. Put the secrets in the `secret`. Mount it on the deployment and rollout the deployment. And the secrets will be available in the container.

Comment: Interesting. I have got the secrets mounted to  /vault/secrets/test
```yaml
sh-4.4$ cat /vault/secrets/test
export dev_database_host="asdf1"
export dev_database_name="asdf2"
```
Unfortunately they still aren't available. I've updated my question with my current config